# Best practice when filtering SQL results using OR in the WHERE part of the statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been using mySQL Quite a bit however, this is the first time I am having to preform a query like the following.  it works but I wonder if there is a better way to write it.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = 10058 or bar = 90234  or bar = 98211 or bar 4002 or bar = 90023
```

Is there a limit to the number of rows I can pull using this methodology?  am I making a  mistake? is there a better way?

FYI  in this particular case bar will always be unique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IN`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN (10058,90234,98211,4002,90023)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could condense the WHERE clause to:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar in (10058,90234,98211,4002,90023)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `foo`
WHERE `bar` IN (10048, 90234, 98211, 4002, 90023)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a `IN` clause like

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar in (10058,90234,98211,4002,90023)
```

Anyways, internally your DB engine will expand it as a OR'ed stack at run time; i.e like

```
WHERE bar = 10058 or bar = 90234  or bar = 98211 or bar 4002 or bar = 90023
```